# Help with equation to find a specific number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, python

I created a program to run a stepper motor with decreasing delays between each step and ends once a value is reached. My problem is that I had to plug in a bunch of numbers until I found a value that matched a desired number of steps the motor took. I was hoping some could help me calculate the value without needing to guess.

Below is the Python code I am using to have my stepper motor reach 2500 steps.

```
delay = 0.01
final_delay = 0.00001
while final_delay < delay:
    delay = delay - (dealy/362.412)
```

The value of "362.412" is the one I refined until this loop completed 2500 steps. How can I find this value without needing to plug in numbers until I reach a desired number of steps?

Thank you for reading this, and any feedback or suggestions you give.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is one or more typo(s) in the last line.  Will that $\textit{while}$ loop ever end?

Comment: @mjw:  yes, it will end.  delay is being reduced by multiplying by a number less than $1$, so it will eventually become less than final delay

Comment: @RossMillikan, yes, got it!  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the last line of the loop could be written as

```
 delay *= 1-1/362.412
```

so that we want to multiply $.01$ by some number $p$, $2500$ times until we get to $.00001$
$$.01\cdot p^{2500}=.00001\\
p=.001^{1/2500}\\
p=0.9972407117415495
$$
Now if you solve $$p=1-\frac1q$$ you'll get $$q=362.4122985111945$$

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick answers. It has been very helpful and allows me to quickly adjust things in the future (if needed).       Also, thank you for the simplification of my code. The one thing that I want to clarify from your solution saulspatz, you found p and then found q? Are there supposed to be two variables?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring floating point errors, each delay is $\frac {361.412}{362.412}$ of the previous one, so you have a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  If your multiplier is $r$ and the first delay is $a$, the delays are $a,ar,ar^2,ar^3\ldots$.  If we start counting terms with $0$, the $n^{th}$ term is $ar^n$ and the sum of the terms from $0$ through $n$ (which is $n+1$ of them) is $a\frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$